# Kotlin inner interface declaration in class

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm

I'm newby in Kotlin and need to re-write the following Java class to Kotlin, and can't figure it out how to implement it.

```
public class TestFragment extends ListFragment {
        
        static interface Listener {
            void itemClicked(long id);
        };


        private Listener listener;



   .....
}
```

So that to use "listener" in @Ovveride onAttach(..) methods as

```
override fun onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context)
listener = context as Listener
}
```

-----------------**UPDATE**--------------------

```
class TestFragment: ListFragment() {

    internal interface Listener {
        fun itemClicked(id: Long)
    }

    private var listener: Listener? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        listener = context as Listener
    }

    override fun onListItemClick(listView: ListView, itemView: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener!!.itemClicked(id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What difficulty are facing in converting this to Koltin??

Comment: The difficulty, an interface reference in class, i.e. how i can refer to refer to interface inside class. Declaring property like var listener = requires initializaion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Android Studio, and you copy-paste this code into your IDE, it will automatically ask you if you want it to convert it into Kotlin on its own.

Try that out.

Nevertheless, if you're trying to create a one-function interface in Kotlin I would recommend you use a [High-Order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks, i have not even thought about Java2Kotlin option in Android Studio. That's where magic lives. Updated my question with final view of class

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer helps you arrive at the conclusion you were looking for, please mark this answer as 'accepted' if you will.